# Stopped martingale: is this a more direct proof to this question?

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, martingales, stopping-times

I'm reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2185993/368425) question by @KennethNg, i.e.,

---

I am reading the Dubins-Schwarz theoem on Brownian motion and stochastic calculus.  It says, given a continuous local martingale $M$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}[M]_t = \infty$ a.s., where $[M]_t$ denotes the quadratic variation of $M$. For each $s \geq 0$, the book defines a stopping time $$T(s)=\inf\{t \geq 0: [M]_t > s\}$$ and says the stopped process $M_{t\wedge T(s)}$ is a martingale.

I would like to ask how can we see the stopped process is indeed a martingale?

---

The accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2186245/368425) by @saz is

---

Let $(\sigma_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a localizing sequence of the local martingale $M$, i.e. an increasing sequence of stopping times such that $\sigma_n \to \infty$ and $(M_{t \wedge \sigma_n})_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Applying the optional stopping theorem, we find that $(M_{t \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)})_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)} \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = M_{u \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)} \tag{1}$$

for all $u \leq t$. Since $M$ has continuous sample paths, the right-hand side converges to $M_{u \wedge T(s)}$ as $n \to \infty$. If we can show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)} \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge T(s)} \mid \mathcal{F}_u)\tag{2}$$

this proves that $(M_{t \wedge T(s)})_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale. To prove $(2)$, we note that by Doob's maximal inequality

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{r \leq t} |M_{r \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)}|^2 \right) &\leq 4 \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)}^2)  = 4 \mathbb{E} \big( [M]_{t \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)} \big) \leq \mathbb{E}([M]_{T(s)}) \leq 4s. \end{align*}$$

By the monotone convergence theorem this implies

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{r \leq t} |M_{r \wedge T(s)}|^2 \right) \leq 4s < \infty.$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |M_{t \wedge \sigma_n \wedge T(s)}| \right) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{r \leq t} |M_{r \wedge T(s)}|^2 \right)} < \infty.$$

Now $(2)$ follows from the dominated convergence theorem.

---

**My question**

@jpv asked in a comment below @saz's answer that

> In (1), shouldn't the conditioning be on $\mathcal{F}_{u \wedge T(s)}$ ?

@saz answered

> Note that there are different version of the OST. The version I'm using is the following: Let $(M_t, \mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a martingale with continuous sample paths and $\sigma$ an $\mathcal{F}_t$-stopping time, then $\left(M_{t \wedge \sigma}, \mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale.

So @saz applied the following OST version, i.e.,

> **OST theorem** Let $(M_t, \mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a martingale with continuous sample paths and $\sigma$ an $\mathcal{F}_t$-stopping time, then $(M_{t \wedge \sigma}, \mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale.

Now come back to @KennethNg's question. We have $T(s)$ is a stopping time and $M$ a martingale, so by above **OST theorem** we get $(M_{t\wedge T(s)})_{t\ge 0}$ is a martingale.

> Could you confirm if my above alternative reasoning is fine?

Comment: The theorem is well known and has certainly many proofs in the standard literature. If your question is not "how to prove it" but don't understand a particular proof in MSE the most natural thing to do would be to discuss this with saz in the relevant thread.

Comment: @KurtG. Unfortunately, the last time when saz was on MSE is one year ago...

Comment: Doesn't matter. You will certainly find a proof in the literature somewhere that satisfies your needs. To get me mildly interested in that new question of yours you should boil it down to a focussed question rather than reproducing snippets of a discussion between the users over there.

Comment: @KurtG. I think I were already focused, i.e., saz provided a proof in which one ingredient is a version of OST (mentioned in a comment). Then I said that with this version, the proof will reduce to just one sentence. Then I asked if my previous understanding is fine.